# When a message read from a queue with Spring Integration is ACK in case of Transacted

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

We have a pipeline in Spring Integration that reads messages from ActiveMQ ( 5 queues ) and then moves those messages across Splitters, Transformers, Aggregators .... and in the end we send the result to a Rest Endpoint.

If we use acknowledge="transacted" , when are those messages ACK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of the inbound channel adapter.

For a message-driven adapter, it's acked when the flow completes (or the container thread hands off to another thread via a queue channel or task executor).

With a polled channel adapter, it's acked immediately, before the flow is invoked, unless you make the poller transactional, in which case, it behaves the same as the message-driven adapter.

Comment: So, if our pipeline can take up to 4 hours to finish, because we need to aggregate messages from diferent sources, probably we should not use "transacted", and use "client" and ack the message manually before the aggregator ?

Comment: Keeping messages un-ack'd for that period of time is not a good design. It sounds like you are trying to use a messaging platform as a database. Transactions can't span multiple sources; I suggest you revisit your design.

Comment: Well, in fact we receive messages from 4 different external sources, with 3 hours of difference, and we aggregate them and release when we have the 4 elements. That's because our process takes too long.

Comment: It just sounds like you should be using a database (or a NoSQL store) to maintain state rather than keeping messages in a transient state for that amount of time.